# Chaining find and distinct

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

In mongodb, chaining find() and distinct() is not allowed. For that, in distinct() they have provided the provision of adding the filter in distinct.

However, in pymongo this chaining is allowed in addition of using the filters in distinct. If however, I chain sort() with find and then distinct(), then distinct does not yield the required results though.

My question is, why this disparity (since this just adds to my mind more conditional checks I need to remember)? what is the advantage of not allowing this chaining in mongodb or is it an overkill done in pymongo

Comment: "why this disparity" - why not? Both ways are equally valid. Let a hundred schools of thought contend. So that everybody can choose something to his liking.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: you see the results are not consistent. if you sort the results of find and then apply distinct on this, in pymongo, the distinct does not yield results according to sort.

Comment: Since pymongo does provide the filter option to distinct, what extra/benefit do we get of the chaining?

Comment: I'm not sure I've seen the problem in the wild (doesn't help that I don't use pymongo). Could you post a [mcve] that demonstrates how distinct returns incorrect results because of sort?

Comment: Along with an example asked above, could you also provide the version of PyMongo?